# How to update one file located in a zip subdirectory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip

I have a zip archive that contains several folders and I need to update one specific file within such  a folder.

How can I update the file with a command line? I have already tried

```
7z u my.zip ./folder/text.file
```

But that places the file into the zip's root.

Also

```
zip -u my.zip ./folder/text.file
```

doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the relative path needs to be the same within the zip and with the directory structure on the file system, from the current directory. Is that the case?

Comment: Ah, it should be `7z u my.zip ./` - that solved the problem. Do you want to add an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relative path needs to be the same within the zip and with the directory structure on the file system, from the current directory.